# Non-allocating k-nearest-neighbours between two matrices in Julia

Tags: performance, algorithm, array, julia

I played around with some optimizations when answering [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70602586/1346276).  Sought is a function which given matrices `x` of size (m, l) and `y` of size (n, l) returns a matrix of size (n, k) where each row consist of the k row numbers in `x` closest to the corresponding row of `y`.  The important requirement was that this should be done without allocation (except for the result array, obviously).

My best solution uses the following "tricks":

- regular views instead of `JuliennedArrays.Slices` I used in my SO answer
- a manually written non-allocating Euclidean distance, with `@fastmath` and no square root (which is unnecessary for sorting)
- linear time replacement function instead of `permutedims`, using the slice of the result matrix as buffer
- more `@inbounds`

```
function replacetop!(result, x; by=identity)
    f_max, i_max = findmax(by, result)
    if by(x) < f_max
        result[i_max] = x
    end
    return result
end

function squared_distance(x, y)
    peeled = Iterators.peel(eachindex(x, y))
    isnothing(peeled) && error("vectors must not be empty")
    i_first, i_rest = peeled
    s = @fastmath (x[i_first] - y[i_first])^2
    @inbounds for i in i_rest
        @fastmath s += (x[i] - y[i])^2
    end
    return @fastmath s
end

function knnslice!(result, x, y)
    @inbounds for (i_r, i_y) in zip(axes(result, 1), axes(y, 1))
        result_row = @view(result[i_r, :])
        fill!(result_row, first(axes(y, 1)))
        f(j) = squared_distance(@view(x[j, :]), @view(y[i_y, :]))
        @inbounds for j_x in axes(x, 1)
            replacetop!(result_row, j_x; by=f)
        end
    end
    return result
end

knnslice(x, y, k) = knnslice!(similar(x, Int, size(y, 1), k), x, y)
```

If we loosen the original interface to better respect column-major order, the following transposed implementation is able to shave off a bit more time:

```
function knnslice_t!(result, x, y)
    @inbounds for (i_r, i_y) in zip(axes(result, 2), axes(y, 2))
        result_row = @view(result[:, i_r])
        fill!(result_row, first(axes(y, 2)))
        f(j) = squared_distance(@view(x[:, j]), @view(y[:, i_y]))
        @inbounds for j_x in axes(x, 2)
            replacetop!(result_row, j_x; by=f)
        end
    end
    return result
end

knnslice_t(x, y, k) = knnslice_t!(similar(x, Int, k, size(y, 2)), x, y)
```

Test cases and benchmarks:

```
x, y = rand(10, 4), rand(5, 4);
xt, yt = permutedims.((x, y));
knnslice(x, y, 5) |> permutedims == knnslice_t(xt, yt, 5)
knnslice([1:10;;], [3;8;;], 3) == [2 3 4; 8 9 7]

@benchmark knnslice!(r, $x, $y) setup=(r = similar(x, Int, size(y, 1), 5))
@benchmark knnslice_t!(r, $xt, $yt) setup=(r = similar(x, Int, 5, size(y, 2)))
```

I'm open for feedback on everything, but especially on the numerics and loop parts; for example, I don't really know what to be careful about with `@fastmath`.  Also, probably there's existing better implementations of `squared_distance`?  Something with even SIMD, maybe?  Does it even pay off with small l?

Comment: It seems to me `knnslice!` doesn't always give correct output. For example, `knnslice([1:10;;], [1;;], 3) == [1 1 1]` instead of `[1 2 3]`. If I understand your intent correctly, I think the `fill!` line should be something like `result_row .= axes(x, 1)[1:length(result_row)]` instead and the `@inbounds for j_x` line should be `@inbounds for j_x in axes(x, 1)[length(result_row)+1:end]`. Similarly for `knnslice_t!`. Could you check this?